# Is there a way to make JQTouch animations faster?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jqtouch

I'm making a android app using PhoneGap and JQTouch.

The animations are starting to get sluggish, is there a way to speed things up?

Is it because I have 2,744 lines of code? 
Because it all loads at one time (at least I think that's how JQTouch works...)

Is there a way to split things up and still keep those beautiful animations?

I'm currently testing the app on a Galaxy S4, that's a 1.9 Ghz proccessor (pretty fast).

Comment: From my experiences this probably does have to do with the amount of code. I recently updated an app I made and added handlebars.js for templating and had a major performance improvement. The issue with I found was that having too many elements loaded into the dom would cause lag and sluggishness. After converting to a templated system, you still have a lot of code, but not all of it is loaded into the dom at the same time and animations really perform well.

Comment: Please explain. What is this template you speak of, links maybe?

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/ it's a JS templating system. You wrap blocks of html in script tags, which keeps your HTML from being loaded completely into the dom at all times. It's very easy to use.

Comment: So tell me, if I had this, what should I do to make it work with handlebars


<div id="page1">
<!-- Header starts here -->
<div class="toolbar">
<h1></h1>
<a class="button back" href="#" style="padding-left:15px;">Back</a>
   </div>
    <!-- The body starts here -->
    This is page #1
    </div>

<div id="page2">
<!-- Header starts here -->
<div class="toolbar">
<h1></h1>
<a class="button back" href="#" style="padding-left:15px;">Back</a>
   </div>
    <!-- The body starts here -->
    This is page #2
    </div>

Comment: can you add that code to your question? also provide some of the code for transitioning between views please.

Comment: I also suggest taking a look at this tutorial. I used this tutorial to completely remake my application and it took very little time. You can cut and paste most of your code to get it started: http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

Comment: Yea.... I don't get it, but thanks anyways...